# How to add signature to StackExchange forum?

Tags: support

I am not able to add a signature. I am not able to find an option to add a signature to Android.stackexchange.com forum. Most of the forums allow adding signatures.

Is there any way to add signature?

Comment: we don't like advertising here ;)

Comment: and we are [not a forum](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/192154) :)

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way. Stack Exchange is all about the content, and signatures just distract from the content. The [Help Center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) is clear about this and provides an alternative: your [profile page](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile).

> #### Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers.
>
> Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!